# Virtual Box and single user install

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I recently uninstalled a VirtualBox installation that was made available to all users using the provided tool. I went to re-install for a single user, but it will only let me install for all users, not single user or specific location. How can I resolve this problem?

I'm using a 2013 MacBook Pro with MacOS Sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, I'm afraid. I filed a [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2054) about this years ago, and it was closed as wontfix.

Comment: Any alternatives that do allow it?

Comment: Not sure... I also use VMWare Fusion and it will certainly run from folders other than /Applications (e.g. ~/Applications), but I don't recall if there's an option to specify install location out of the box.